# Workflow Instance to multiple users accessing

Tags: workflow-foundation

i am present working on workflows with asp.net in that i had one doubt, workflow is running its instance to one user, when he submit one form the data submited to be send to workflow variables,
here when multiple people could invoke workflow at that time multiple instance id are created to them and how the instance will be handled when they working on one workflow ?.
1)is the workflow will generate different instance id to different users?.
2)how the data to be stored in variables at workflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can configure that in the way that you want. That't totally depends on your business scenario (Logic in the workflow).
2. You can have variables in workflows if you want to have long running workflows you need to configure a persistence store to save them to some storage(Ex :SQL server DB)